# RSA Extra Bit 129 instead off 128

Tags: c#, rsa, biginteger

I am using this function to change public key and encrypt data:

```
public byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data2Encrypt)
{
    string key = "109120132967399429278860960508995541528237502902798129123468757937266291492576446330739696001110603907230888610072655818825358503429057592827629436413108566029093628212635953836686562675849720620786279431090218017681061521755056710823876476444260558147179707119674283982419152118103759076030616683978566631413";
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

    BigInteger intk;
    BigInteger.TryParse(key, out intk);

    RSAParameters privateKey = new RSAParameters();
    byte[] expont = { 1, 0, 1 };
    byte[] modulus = intk.ToByteArray();

    Logger.log(Log_Type.ERROR, "Pierwszy bit: " + modulus[0]);
    privateKey.Exponent = expont;
    privateKey.Modulus = intk.ToByteArray();

    rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);
    return rsa.Encrypt(data2Encrypt, false);
}
```

But it return me array with 129 length instead od 128 (What should be max lenght using 1024 bits i think). What can be a reason?

Comment: The key size has little to do with the ciphertext size.

Comment: This key is used on another projects and works just fine (not mine, i am crypto noob). What i see that intk.toByArray lenght is 129 too.. but i don't know how to fix it correct.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not true for RSA. The ciphertext length of RSA encryption is directly related to the [size of the key's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Encryption).

Comment: @Syon you're right about that, but OP seems to think the maximum ciphertext length equals the key length.

Comment: @Syon with RSA key size = 4096, `Encrypt` returns 550 bytes (???) array. So when I use it in `Decrypt` call - I always get Exception, because `Decrypt` expects the input array size is ALWAYS = modulus size (512 bytes)... What the...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BigInteger` produces signed little-endian numbers, while `RSAParameters` requires unsigned big-endian. You can still use `BigInteger` though, just convert its output to what `RSAParameters` is expecting.

```
byte[] modulus = intk.ToByteArray().Reverse().Skip(1).ToArray();
```

`Reverse` to make the number big-endian, and `Skip(1)` to skip the sign.

Answer (score 2):

If you use BigInteger an additional bit is always placed before the 
number. If your key has 1024 bits you get 1025 bits, so skip the 
first byte if it is 0x00 (meaning a positive value)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, that it should be even converted into BitInteger. RSA key what I am trying to get is similar to this function in C++

```
void Crypt::rsaSetPublicKey(const std::string& n, const std::string& e)
{
BN_dec2bn(&m_rsa->n, n.c_str());
BN_dec2bn(&m_rsa->e, e.c_str());

// clear rsa cache
if(m_rsa->_method_mod_n) { BN_MONT_CTX_free(m_rsa->_method_mod_n); m_rsa->_method_mod_n = NULL; }
```

}

Where 'n' is this key srting and 'e' is : "65537"

If it should not be a BigInteger, then what?